# Read multiple files into single list using pipes

Tags: r

I have a number simple files with a single entry per line and I want to read those files into a list with the content of a file as a vector.

```
> list(file_one = c(1,2,3,4), file_two = c(9,99,999))
$file_one
[1] 1 2 3 4

$file_two
[1]   9  99 999

...
```

This is basically the resulting format i want.
What I have so far is a similar result, but not correct:

```
> list.files("/home/x/y/z", pattern="^rep.*List$", full.names=TRUE) %>% lapply(read.table)

[[1]]
    V1
1   a
2   b
3   c
4   d
```

How can I read the data in the correct format or transform it from here? - preferably I would have a "pipeline" to read the data:

1. list files
2. read files in correct format or
3. format the read data into a list of named vectors

Comment: Can you add info about the directory that you're getting files from? Right now I don't know what that regex is supposed to return, or what gets you "a", "b", etc.

Comment: the files are named rep1List, rep2List, rep3List etc. "a", "b", "c" are the first three lines of the first read file (rep1List).

Comment: It's easier to follow if you put that in your question. Maybe with a mockup of the file tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you need something like this

```
library(tidyverse)

list.files("xyz/", full.names = TRUE) %>% 
  set_names(basename(.)) %>% 
  map(read_lines)

#> $`rep1List`
#> [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f"
#> 
#> $rep2List
#> [1] "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" "k"
#> 
#> $rep3List
#> [1] "l" "m" "m" "o" "p" "q" "r" "s"
```

where each of the files look like this:
[image: img]

Answer (score 0):

based on the information you gave, I would try something like below, using the purrr-Package:

```
list.files("/home/x/y/z", pattern="^rep.*List$", full.names = TRUE) %>% 
  purrr::map_df(., read.table, ADD YOUR ARGUMENTS HERE)
```

This is working for a real-life example for me. It fails with your made up file. I would have just commented, but I am too low. ^^